# Child elements flowing out of parent in Firefox

Tags: html, css

In Chrome, when I search for recipes on my website, it will stretch the element with the id of `recipeSection` to fit all the recipes that match the search request.

However in Firefox, the child elements will just flow on out of the parent element (or when I open dev tools, they all smush together to fit in the container??).

I've done a lot of research on positioning and flow in the last couple hours and looking at similar questions on StackOverflow - I've been yet to find anything that can fix my issue. Any ideas?

You can test it at this [website](https://www.pantrypal.xyz)

Just put in any ingredient in the searchbox at the top of the page. Flour works. The project uses materialize framework but it's not being used very much here.

```css
#recipeSection {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.recipeStyle {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 2.5%;
  padding: 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  color: #2d2d2d;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'mada';
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.recipeTitle {
  width: 80%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="recipeSection">
  <div class="recipeStyle card grey lighten-5">
    <div class="recipeTitle">Example Recipe Title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="recipeStyle card grey lighten-5">
    <div class="recipeTitle">Example Recipe Title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="recipeStyle card grey lighten-5">
    <div class="recipeTitle">Example Recipe Title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="recipeStyle card grey lighten-5">
    <div class="recipeTitle">Example Recipe Title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="recipeStyle card grey lighten-5">
    <div class="recipeTitle">Example Recipe Title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="recipeStyle card grey lighten-5">
    <div class="recipeTitle">Example Recipe Title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="recipeStyle card grey lighten-5">
    <div class="recipeTitle">Example Recipe Title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="recipeStyle card grey lighten-5">
    <div class="recipeTitle">Example Recipe Title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="recipeStyle card grey lighten-5">
    <div class="recipeTitle">Example Recipe Title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="recipeStyle card grey lighten-5">
    <div class="recipeTitle">Example Recipe Title</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: you can find it in the link in the post, I included this because this will replicate the exact behavior with all the context - but I can include pertinent code if you like

Comment: Have you tried applying the overflow: hidden css attribute to the parent container?

Comment: Yes. The child elements continue to flow out of the parent, but are then hidden once they leave the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the padding and margin to be measured in px instead of a percentage has solved the issue. not entirely sure why - is this percentage not being calculated into the height created by auto, leaving the parent container not to be large enough for its child elements? That seems like a peculiar interaction.